# windows phone 8 how to check network availability

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, internet-connection

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 App with C# and my app needs to realize automatically when the network availability has changed.

So, when the Windows Phone is suddenly connected to the internet I need to take some actions, but I really do not know how to check this. I don't want to set a Timer, running constantly in a Thread for checking this every couple of seconds.

Is there any Method (similar to the `OnNavigatedTo` method), that is launched automatically, when the phone connects to the internet?

If so, what is the best and most efficient way to implement this?

Thank you for all tips and your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is [NetworkAvailabilityChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You can find all available information in the [DeviceNetworkInformation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

use this nameSpace

using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

```
 if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
   {
     //Do something
   }
   else
   {
      //Do Something
   }
```

Comment: What will this check return, if your phone is connected to a pc, that has no Internet connection? I've used this solution before, and remember, there was a bug, that required additional check. Sadly, I don't remember precisely, what that bug was about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Hollywood principle instead of polling:

[NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check network availability in .Net Framework 2.0 using

```
if(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
  //Do your stuffs when network available

}
else
{
  //Do stuffs when network not available

}
```

It will return `true` or `false`.