# Windows Phone 8.1: Check Internet Connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, internet-connection

How can I know if the phone has internet connection? (Whether WiFi or Data)

Sometimes the phone is connecting to WiFi without internet connection like HotSpots. So I want a code to know if the phone is connecting to internet.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362646/windows-phone-8-how-to-check-network-availability help?

Comment: what do you need it for? web service ?

Comment: Before I call the web service I want to know if the user is connecting to the internet or not...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try:

```
 if (NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile() == null)
        {
            //no connection
        }
```

As you can see in this msdn documentation:[NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx)

It will return **null** if there is "no connection profile with a suitable connection"

You can also check explicity the "Internet Access" level with this: `NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess`

I Think this will work also in universal app.

Answer (score 1):

The below Method works for me simply to check if the device is connected to internet or not even in universal windows app. After creating the connection class you can simply use it anywhere just by instantiating this class...

```
public class Connection
{
   public bool CheckInternetAccess()
   {
        var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        var HasInternetAccess = (connectionProfile != null &&
                             connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() ==
                             NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
        return HasInternetAccess;
   }
}
```

To use this class simply..

```
 Connection objConnection = new Connection();
 if(objConnection.CheckInternetAccess()==true)
 {
   //todo
 }
 else
 {//todo}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a captive portal, which is pretty much a page that users connect to, to test whether their internet connection is working, it can be explained [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) in greater detail.

These open source projects look promising:

1. [WiFiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/)
2. [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.org/)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider checking internet in background thread

```
if (await Task.Run(() =>NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
   //Wifi or Cellular
}
else
{
   // No internet
}
```