# How can I determine whether I am connected to WiFi or a mobile network in Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal app)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services, connectivity, win-universal-app

I am working with a Windows Universal app (shared backend between Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, not Silverlight). The app connects to Azure with Azure Mobile Services. In the settings for the app I would like to have an option for synchronisation to only occur over a WiFi network.

How can I determine if the phone is connected to WiFi or a mobile network? Although from my research I have found ways to do this with older versions of Windows Phone and with Silverlight, it seems I can only determine if the device is connected to the internet in a Windows Universal app.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/d8e76732-19d3-47b3-840f-70d87c75ce9f/network-checking-in-winrt) or [this blog post](http://www.guruumeditation.net/blog/internet-connection-type-detection-in-winrt) will help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can determine this information from the [`ConnectionProfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.aspx) using something akin to:

```
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;

var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
// connectionProfile can be null (e.g. airplane mode)
if (connectionProfile != null && connectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile) {
    // do something over WiFi;
}
```

There is also the `IsWwanConnectionProfile` property, which is used to determine if the connection is via a 'mobile' connection (3g, etc).

Comment: Please note: This applies to Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 only! see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207005(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @UtsavDawn  I threw this code into a new universal application (windows phone & windows store app), and it worked without issue. The [documentation for the Windows.Networking.Connectivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx) makes no mention of it being a silverlight API.

Comment: At first I didn't think this was working, but the "connectionProfile != null" is important! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I modified it after I wrote it to deal with the null connectionProfile because it crashed when using airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the only way to check for internet availability :

```
bool IsConnected = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something different
        }
```

This [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452991.aspx) is my reference.

Comment: Does this determine if the connection is WiFi or if the connection is mobile network, or just a general network connection?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647505/windows-phone-8-1-check-internet-connection

Comment: I know how to check for an internet connection, but I'm looking for a way to determine if that connection is through WiFi or through mobile data (sorry if that wasn't clear before).

Comment: This is only available in Windows Phone Silverlight, not WinRT API.