# How can I have a label in C# show how I am using the internet?

Tags: c#, operating-system

I need to figure out how I can make C# display how I am connected to the internet. For example say Windows has a little icon in the corner saying either wifi or ethernet. I want to figure out how I can do that in a C# form using a label.

Please Help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, we don't write code for you, we only help you with the code you have already written. Have you tried anything yet? If so, post it up here in the question, and we can help you from there.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. There was nothing I could find.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852810/how-can-i-determine-whether-i-am-connected-to-wifi-or-a-mobile-network-in-window and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/d8e76732-19d3-47b3-840f-70d87c75ce9f/network-checking-in-winrt

Comment: @appleoper If you are attempting to use your program to connect to the internet, you could simply throw in an extra step to show the status. Eg, after you (successfully) connect, simply set `label.Text = "Connected"`; after you disconnect (successfully) `label.Text = "Disconnected"`. I realise this is incredibly crude, but without knowing how your are attempting to do this, that's pretty much the extent of the help we can provide.